# Angular : Not Able to Auto populate radio button field Based on other date fields

Tags: html, angular, typescript, datepicker

There are two date fields plannedRatingDate and PlannedRatingCommitteeDate on my UI. 
If the user fills in plannedRatingDate field,rcReview field should be set to 'No'.
If the user fills in plannedRatingCommitteeDate field,rcReview field should be set to 'Yes'.
 rcReview field is a radio button field on my UI.

In app.component.html:

```
<tr>   
<td colspan="2"></td>
              <td style="width:500px">
                <label for="PlannedReviewDate">Planned Review Date</label>
                <input id="PlannedReviewDate" name="PlannedReviewDate" (change)="basedOnRatingDate($event)" [(ngModel)]="deal.plannedReviewDate" placement="right" type="text" bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig" class="form-control">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3"></td>
              <td><label for="isReviewComplete">Is Review Complete?</label>
                <input id="isReviewComplete" name="isReviewComplete" [(ngModel)]="deal.isReviewComplete" type="radio" class="form-control" value="Complete">
                Complete<br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3"></td>
              <td><input id="isReviewComplete" name="isReviewComplete" [(ngModel)]="deal.isReviewComplete" type="radio" class="form-control" value="Not Complete">
                Not Complete<br></td>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3"></td>
              <td style="width:500px">
                <label for="PlannedRatingCommitteeDate">Planned rating committee date</label>
                <input id="PlannedRatingCommitteeDate" name="PlannedRatingCommitteeDate" (change)="populateRCReview($event)" [(ngModel)]="deal.plannedRatingCommitteeDate" placement="right" type="text" bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig" class="form-control">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <br>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3"></td>
              <td>
                <label>RC Review</label>
                <input id="rcReview" name="rcReview" [(ngModel)]="deal.rcReview" type="radio" class="form-control" value="Yes">
                Yes<br>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3"></td>
              <td>
                <input id="rcReview" name="rcReview" [(ngModel)]="deal.rcReview" type="radio" class="form-control" value="No">
              No<br>
            </td>
            </tr>
```

In app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'angular-app';
  name = 'angular-app';
  datePickerConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;
  dropdownList = [];
  selectedItems: any;
  selected:any;
  dropdownSettings:IDropdownSettings;
  dealid : number;
  isReviewComplete: any;
  plannedRatingCommitteeDate: Date;
  plannedReviewDate: Date;
  ExpectedReleaseDate: Date;
  ReleaseTimeCriteria: any;
  SubsequentRating: any;
  Priority: any;
  rcReview: any;
  ApplicationReceived: any;
  subsequentRating: any;
  deal:DealApi= new DealApi();
  constructor(private service:HttpclientService) {}
  ngOnInit(){

   this.datePickerConfig = Object.assign({},{ containerClass:'theme-dark-blue', showWeekNumbers: false});

  };
  public savenow(){
    this.service.getdeals(this.deal).subscribe((data:any)=>{alert("Deal added successfully.");});
   }
   basedOnRatingDate(event:any){
    this.deal.rcReview = "No";
   }
   populateRCReview(event:any){
    this.deal.rcReview = "Yes";
   }
```

Above code is not autopopulating rcReview field with 'No' if user enters plannedRatingDate field.
What changes should be done?

Any Help will be appreciated!

Comment: you want to autopopulate when you enter value?

Comment: Yes.When user enters date in plannedRatingDate field,rcReview should be set to No.

Comment: Have you tried input event?

Comment: Can you post a example on how to do that?

Comment: check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iejyjz

Comment: Input event is not working in my code.When I enter plannedRatingCommittee date,it is setting rcReview to Yes but when I enter plannedRatingDate it is not changing the rcReview to No

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Difference between your stackblitz example and my code is using datepicker for selecting date.That is why autopopulating is not happening properly.What solution do you suggest in this scenario because I need to use datepicker for selecting date?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by using **ngModelChange** event instead of change event.